How do I play the Minecraft Dungeons & Dragons DLC on Java Edition?
I would like to play the Minecraft Dungeons & Dragons DLC, but I struggle to understand how.
I have Minecraft Java Edition on Windows 10 using the Minecraft Launcher. When I go to this site, where you can buy the DLC and click on "Get this Item" I am redirected to this blank page ('Unbenannt' is German for 'Untitled'):

Furthermore on my Launcher I have these pages:

I have only been using the Java Edition one so far, to play the base game. But which one of these do I go to buy/play the DLC?
I am starting to suspect that this DLC might be only for Bedrock edition, is that correct? If so, is there any way to get this playing on Java? Or do I maybe somehow get Bedrock Edition without having to pay extra for it, if I already own Java Edition?

You can't play it on Java, but you can get Bedrock without issue
The DLC is being sold on the Minecraft Marketplace, which is exclusively for Bedrock, as suspected. However as also suspected if you own Java Editon, you also own Bedrock, as explained in this article.
As to the question about which widget to click on the launcher, it is the second one "Minecraft for Windows", as that is actually Bedrock Edition. Clicking on it might however tell you that your launcher is incompatible with it, which was the case for me. This can be fixed by going into the Microsoft Store and updating the launcher (don't forget to close the launcher, or it can't update).
The updated launcher is actually a different app. The old one has a greyish, beige Creeper symbol and the new one a green one. This is probably to indicate that the old one is no longer up to date.

Now with the Launcher updated and Bedrock Editon ready to play, the formerly blank page redirects correctly to Bedrock edition on the Launcher and opens the page for the DLC. Otherwise the DLC can also be accessed by launching the game, going into the Marketplace there and then searching for it. The DLC can be bought for 1510 Minecoins or 8,99€.

